# Why does unordered_map take two values?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm just not getting it - why does this initialize a 2 parameter value?

I know there's a key and value...but do I need to specifically give the key every time? Doesn't this have an internal hashing function?

I have a question that's : "Given 2 arrays, find common numbers + different numbers". Simple enough. Though my issue is actually implementing the STL container "unordered_map" because I can't find anything explicitly explaining why it takes two parameters.

What I wanna' do:

```
unordered_map<int> hash;
hash.insert(5);

if ( hash.find(5) == true)
{
  cout << "Okay, got it. It's in the hash table." << endl;
}
```

So something like that so you can get the gist. Just not sure why there are two values like:

```
unordered_map<int, int> hash;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not a `map` without a key, what you probably want is a [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: is it possible that you dont want a map, but a `std::set`?

Comment: More precisely, if he wants a hashed container, then he should use `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: The standard map types are [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), so they take two types

Comment: Ah. I figured I may want a set - so then if I want to hash in values to check if they exist against another array - that should itself be a reason to use set right? For some reason I was under the impression that set isn't hashed.

Comment: @Travis Specifically `std::unordered_set`, yes. `std::set`/`std::map` uses a Tree Structure to store items, `std::unordered_set`/`std::unordered_map` uses a hash table to store items.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] but do I need to specifically give the key every time?

Yes! Thats what a map is about. If you dont care about the key, then you probably dont want a map, but a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be "if you don't care about the value"? Keys are unique in a map, values can be repeated.

Comment: @Barmar probably you are right. I stayed with OPs wording: wants to store unique values, but wonders why needs to give the keys. And values are unique in a set, so they can be considered as keys... I dont know.. feel free to edit in case you know how to phrase it better

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, a map isn't really what you're looking for.

What they've advised instead is a set (or unordered_set).

At least IMO, this is *somewhat* questionable as well. It's clearly a lot better fit, *but* given the circumstances (you want to take two lists, find what numbers they contain, then find the intersection/difference) you'd probably be better off putting the numbers into vectors, then using `sort` and `unique` to remove duplicates. A `set` or `unordered_set` will typically work better if you need to do insertions and deletions and *maintain* uniqueness as you do so. A vector tends to work better when/if you can store all the data, then sort it, then ensure uniqueness--and once you've done that, you don't need to modify that list again.

Finally, you should also take note of `std::set_intersection` and `std::set_difference` (or possibly `std::set_symmetric_difference`). These will take a set of inputs that have been sorted (but *not* necessarily stored in an `std::set`) and find (obviously enough) the intersection and difference between the two lists of numbers--exactly what you apparently need as your result.

Comment: Wow. Thyis was an amazing concise answer. Thank you!

Comment: nice example of the correct answer not being the one that takes the question too literally ;)